What API-method to use to validate a lot of data
I have two different requests that relate to single resource.
Let's call it "subjects".
One of them validate "subjects" every time user do some action. Let's call it "validate".
Second record "subjects" when user is done. Lets' call it "record". Also we should note that this request can UPDATE data, can CREATE data, but can't DUPLICATE existing data (on conflict via UUID);
We have the same required data for both requests:
It's UUID and List (Array);
For example, data can be something like this:
{
    request_uid: "cd8ef6fd-5ea2-4087-9e8b-6ad5104f0096",
    subjects: ["fullAbsenceSubject", "damageSubject", "innerShortageSubject", "weightDifferenceSubject"]
}

I want single prefix for both requests.
Let's suggests it is "/subjects".
I need help in choosing what solution will be the best for REST-API:
1.
Record Subjects -> POST or PUT with "/subjects" prefix,
Validate Subjects -> GET with "/subjects" prefix (I'm not sure I want to record this huge list in URI)
2.
Record Subjects -> PUT with "/subjects" prefix,
Validate Subjects -> POST with "/subjects" prefix
3.
Record Subjects -> POST or PUT with "/subjects" prefix,
Validate Subjects -> POST or PUT with "/subjects/validate" prefix
4.
I'm open for any new suggestions

Validation should be done on creating or updating a record, as an invalid record should not exist. GET only returns a valid record that already exists.

@chepner, got it, thanks

for your HTTP2 routing:
  POST /subjects => CREATE entry
   PUT /subjects => UPDATE entry
   GET /subjects =>   LIST entry
DELETE /subjects =>   DROP entry

handle validation of duplicate entries in the POST method logic.
handle security in middleware to authenticate / authorize all actions.
consider DELETE later, when business case arises.


What API-method to use to validate a lot of data

TL;DR: POST


POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of “this action isn’t worth standardizing.” -- Roy Fielding, 2009

You are intended to send a request with a body to the server, so GET is out of bounds, even though the intended semantics of the request are "safe".
The closest thing you have to a safe method is probably QUERY; it's certainly safe, but not yet a registered HTTP method (as the specification is still a draft).
The request body of a QUERY is supposed to be the "input parameters to the query operation" -- though as far as I can tell the entire request body can be a single parameter (in other words, it's not clear to me what assumptions general purpose components are allowed to make about the payload, and therefore how our API designs might be constrained by those assumptions).

For the actual "do it" method with the unsafe semantics; you want to use PUT if it's appropriate (the message is that the server should make it's private representation of the target resource look like the enclosed payload), and POST in the (often common) cases where PUT semantics don't match.
So before you default to using PUT, make sure you understand the assumptions that general purpose components are allowed to make.

There's nothing "against the rules" about giving POST /foo different meanings/handlers depending on the contents of the requests; it's trade offs all the way down.  You of course will need to define things cleverly enough that the server can distinguish which "meaning" is intended by the client.
Using two different resources, eg POST /foo and POST /bar is OK too - the trade offs are a bit different (general purpose components won't guess that /foo and /bar are the "same thing"; which is a disadvantage in some contexts).
